# Personalize mint instalation - Add created user to different groups

Tags: installation, linux-mint, xfce

I'm personalizing a linux mint install iso (linuxmint-18.3-xfce-64bit) using JLIVECD.
What I would like to know is if it is possible to run some script or edit some files in order to add the created user in the installation to some groups (tty and lp).
The idea is:
User boot the iso and choose to install.
At some point in the installation process, the user will be asked to create a user.
The installation works normally.
After reboot, the created user will belong to some additional groups (tty and lp)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Although not a direct answer to my question, it solved my problem.
I edited /etc/adduser.conf , a file that defines the options to be used when a new user is created.
The options:

```
EXTRA_GROUPS="dialout tty lp"
ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=1
```

add new created users (even if created in the install wizard) to secondary groups.